# Python 3 - Searching in OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm fairly new to programming and have been self teaching myself python in my free time.  I'm really trying to under stand OOP and have hit a wall.  This is a smaller example of a larger program I am writing.

```
class Emp():
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

    def PrintEmp(self):
        return (self.first, self.last, self.age)

employee = {}

employee[0] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jacob', 'Last': 'Jones', 'Age': 31}}
employee[1] = {'Info': {'First': 'Joe', 'Last': 'Smith', 'Age': 45}}
employee[2] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jim', 'Last': 'Bob', 'Age': 38}}
employee[3] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jack', 'Last': 'Black', 'Age': 21}}
employee[4] = {'Info': {'First': 'Joey', 'Last': 'John', 'Age': 39}}
employee[5] = {'Info': {'First': 'Job', 'Last': 'God', 'Age': 99}}

for key in employee:
    employee[key]['Info']['First'] = Emp(employee[key]['Info']['First'],
                                     employee[key]['Info']['Last'],
                                     employee[key]['Info']['Age'])

choice = input('Employee')

for key in employee:
    if choice == employee[key]['Info']['First']:
        print(choice.PrintEmp)
        #choice.first, choice.last, choice.age ect...
    else:
        print("This isn't working")
```

I am basically trying to search through a list of known employees and then print anything from the actual object or just search directly through the objects for specific attributes.

Comment: Is something not working as you'd expected? What is the question you're hoping to have answered?

Comment: You don't need to create a dictionary of `info`. You even don't need dictionary of each person. Better create separate objects of `Emp` and add them in a list. Then do a search query over the list using inline `for` loop.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad - It never occured to me to just "make" an object without a label and place them in a list.  This is how I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted by [dm03514](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594589/dm03514) your `if-condition` did not work, because you were comparing a string with a class instance.

Next issue, PrintEmp() is a function of Emp and not choice, therefore `print(choice.PrintEmp)` does not work.

You may want to try this:

```
class Emp():
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

    def PrintEmp(self):
        return (self.first, self.last, self.age)

employee = {}

employee[0] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jacob', 'Last': 'Jones', 'Age': 31}}
employee[1] = {'Info': {'First': 'Joe', 'Last': 'Smith', 'Age': 45}}
employee[2] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jim', 'Last': 'Bob', 'Age': 38}}
employee[3] = {'Info': {'First': 'Jack', 'Last': 'Black', 'Age': 21}}
employee[4] = {'Info': {'First': 'Joey', 'Last': 'John', 'Age': 39}}
employee[5] = {'Info': {'First': 'Job', 'Last': 'God', 'Age': 99}}


employees = []
for key in employee:
    employees.append(
        Emp(
            employee[key]['Info']['First'],
            employee[key]['Info']['Last'],
            employee[key]['Info']['Age']
        )
    )

choice = input('Employee first name:\n')

for employee in employees:
    if choice == employee.first:
        print (employee.PrintEmp())
    else:
        print("This isn't working")
```

Returns for 'Jim':

```
This isn't working
This isn't working
('Jim', 'Bob', 38)
This isn't working
This isn't working
This isn't working
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, after reading this I was able to fix my code.  Essentially I have a large .json file that I was reading into the program and each key was placed into the object with its values being the attributes.  I literally just wanted to have a prompt that will allow me to search through the database and print the given key with it's attributes.  I was fixed on having to name each individual object (emp1 = Emp(args)) and trying to search for emp1 essentially.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

`choice` probably wont match anything because you're comparing the user input string to an `Emp` instance.

If you removed:

```
for key in employee:
    employee[key]['Info']['First'] = Emp(employee[key]['Info']['First'],
                                     employee[key]['Info']['Last'],
                                     employee[key]['Info']['Age'])
```

You should be able to at least iterate through and match employees based on First name.

---

As for OOP, I would recommend starting at SOLID, which are 5 design principles and provide a great guideline for OOP development.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

I think their strongest suite is that they give us some concepts to evaluate code by, and give us a place to start talking, and provide us with shared terminology.

---

2 amazingly useful concepts of programming and OOP are: encapsulation and delegation.

I could imagine a collection of employees that exposes a `search()` method.  This would insulate your main code from having to change as your improve/change your search implementation and it isolates search logic to only parts of the program that require to know the specifics of it.

Comment: SOLID seems to be a version of REPL for OOP.  SOLID is a good concept to remember for future endeavors.  Thanks.  

Ultimately will be placing a search() method in my code.  Baby steps though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming! I started teaching myself a little under a year ago, so I can relate to any frustrations that may arise when learning a new concept.

I'll start with what you're trying to accomplish first - invoking your `PrintEmp` method of an `Emp` instance. The reason your current code isn't working as you would like is because you're iterating through every `employee` (When I think you really just want to find a match), and then your condition will never evaluate as intended because `choice` is a `str` object and your keys in `employee` are integers. In the following example I start by grabbing the dictionary containing the needed values to create an instance of `Emp` with `info = value['Info']`. Of the dictionary now stored in the variable `info` I can grab the values I need with `info.values()` and then I [unpack](https://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) those values as arguments for each `Emp` instance that is created. Now that each dictionary has been converted to an `Emp` object we can call `PrintEmp` as we'd like.

Note: I took the liberty of changing your naming of the dictionary `employee` to `employees` as it's a bit more accurate.

```
# Here we instantiate each `employee`
for key, value in employees.items():
    info = value['Info']  # e.g. here I now have {'First': 'Jacob', 'Last': 'Jones', 'Age': 31}

    # Now I am going to create an `Emp` instance for each dictionary in `employees`
    employees[key] = Emp(*info.values())

choice = int(input('Enter an employee index: '))

if choice in employees:
    print(employees[choice].PrintEmp())
else:
    "That still isn't working..."
```

Running the program now:

```
>>> Enter an employee index: 2
returning: ('Jim', 'Bob', 38)
```

Say you wanted to format the output of your `PrintEmp` method - you can use the `str.format` method like so:

```
def PrintEmp(self):
    # Note the type conversion for self.age
    return "Hi my name is {} {}, and I'm {}!".format(self.first, self.last, str(self.age))
```

Running the program now:

```
>>> Enter an employee index: 2
returning: Hi my name is Jim Bob, and I'm 38!
```

If there's anything you would like clarification on, don't hesitate to ask!